# Manipulating large files that are being used

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to retrieve handles of very large files (hundreds GB to x TB) that are being used by some processes. I am thinking about turning off the running processes for a while then copying them to some specific location. But this approach looks clumsy for a couple of reasons.

1. Files are too large, so copying them from place to place takes time 
   on different disk types.
2. After the file copy process is done, I have to turn on the stopped processes. But what if my users need to load/copy other large
   files whose handles the said processes are controling ? I    have to stop them again. I don't want to do this
   because they have to do many critical tasks in my machine.

So I have 2 questions,

1. Please explain that my approach is wrong. What I say above is only
   my personal idea, no coding is done yet for any of it.
2. Are there any methods to clone ~50 large files (1-5 TB) fast (some ten seconds or so) and silently in the background ?

Comment: What's the read/write speed of the disk array holding the files?  If it's less than 1-5Tb/s /10 then you're not going to do it in less than 10 seconds ever.

Comment: How would you *"turn off the running processes"*? You cannot just kill them, without risking to lose data. And you cannot suspend them either, because they will still have handles to the files open, so that doesn't buy you anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the original process opens the file in non-sharing mode (seems likely for such large files) you are probably out of luck for doing this without closing that process - or at least getting it to relinquish the file. If it allows at least read sharing I would suggest you use transactional NTFS - despite the warnings on all the docs about that.

Create a KTM transaction manager (via CreateTransactionManager), create a KTM transaction (with CreateTransaction) then use CopyFileTransacted to do the actual copy. Finally commit the transaction (CommitTransaction) and then close all the handles. Doing it this way will ensure that the file is in a consistent state (no partial writes from the original process).

It may also be that the backup API can ignore share mode (I know it can ignore security checks if your process has the appropriate privileges enabled, not sure about sharing).